# Develop a class averaging program that will process an arbitrary number of grades each time the program run

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int grade,count,sum,average;
grade=0;
count=0;
sum=0;
while(grade!=-1)
{
printf("enter grade=");
scanf("%d",&grade);
sum=grade+sum;
count=count++;
}
average=sum/count;
printf("the average is=%d",average);
return 0;
}
```

[this is the question and the output!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rmVy.png)
i have a homework to do this exercise i wrote it but i dont know where is wrong so plz guys i want a little help !!!
thanks

Comment: `count=count++;` - replace by `count++;` Or by `count = count + 1;`

Comment: Hey, don't edit your question. It is not your compiler, so it *should* show the wrong code

Comment: the code run but the average is wrong

Comment: Because you calculate it and print as integer.

Comment: i put the first integer 1 and the second 1 the average should be 1+1/2=1 but in output they said average =0

Comment: your count will be 1 larger than it should be at all times because your count will increment even when the input is -1, try checking the input directly after the scanf like: if(grade == -1) { break;}

Comment: i should do it using only while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few problematic lines in the code that you should fix.

```
count=count++;
```

as pointed out by Eugene's comments, count++ is similar to count = count + 1. This line should only be one of those. think of "count = count++" as "count = count = count + 1" which is a very odd way to format an increment. This line should only be `count++;`

```
average=sum/count;
```

This line is doing integer division, where your question is looking for floating point answers. You can force these two integers to perform floating point division by multiplying it by 1.0 (a floating point value). It should look like this:

```
average = 1.0 * sum / count;
```

Finally, your loop will increment the counter each time no matter what is input, as well as add it to the sum. When -1 is input, it will increment the count and add it to the sum before the while loop has ended. You can put these operations into a simple if statement to ensure this is accounted for:

```
printf("enter grade=");
scanf("%d",&grade);
if (grade >= 0) {
    sum=grade+sum;
    count++;
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Note: This does not account for the case where no numbers are input before -1, I will leave this for you to play with, you can come back to this question if you have further issues

Comment: how  we can solve the -1 input to  print no grades entered i cant solve it

Comment: After the while loop has ended (User input -1) you would want to check that your count variable is greater than 0 before calculating the average and printing it.